# Bounding diagonal elements of special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a strictly substochastic matrix, let $x$ be a scalar with $x\in[0,1]$, and let $$\Lambda(x)\equiv(I-xA^{T})^{-1}.$$ Let $v$ be a vector satisfying $v_{i}\in[0,1],\forall i$ and $\sum_{i}v_{i}=1$.  Consider the matrix
$$J(v,x)=\left(\mathrm{diag}\left(\Lambda(x)v\right)\right)^{-1}\Lambda(x)\left[x\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right)+(1-x)\mathrm{diag}\left(\Lambda(x)v\right)\right]\Lambda^{T}(x)\mathrm{diag}\left(I-A\iota\right),$$ which can also be written as
$$J(v,x)=S(v,x)\left[xI+(1-x)\left(\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right)\right)^{-1}\mathrm{diag}\left(\Lambda(x)v\right)\right]\Lambda^{T}(x)\mathrm{diag}\left(I-A\iota\right),$$ where $$S(v,x) \equiv \left(\mathrm{diag}\left(\Lambda(x)v\right)\right)^{-1}\Lambda(x)\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right).$$   I want to show that the maximum diagonal element of $J(v,x)$ is weakly lower than one for all $v,x$.

In fact, simulations suggest that this is true even for the spectral radius of $J(v,x)$, and in a separate question () I asked about that, but so far with no luck. I am now looking to prove this easier statement.

For the case in which $x = 1$ we have $$J(v,1)=S(v,1) (I-A)^{-1}\mathrm{diag}\left(I-A\iota\right).$$ $S(v,\iota)$ is a stochastic matrix, while $$\left(I-A\right)^{-1}\mathrm{diag}\left(I-A\iota\right)\iota=\left(I-A\right)^{-1}\left(I-A\right)\iota=\iota,$$ so matrix $\left(I-A\right)^{-1}\mathrm{diag}\left(I-A\iota\right)$ is also stochastic, so it follows that $J(v,\iota)$ is substochastic and hence all elements are weakly lower than one.

If $x = 0$ then $J(v,0) = \mathrm{diag}(I-A\iota).$ This is a diagonal matrix with all elements between zero and one.

In the special case in which $A$ is a diagonal matrix then $S(v,x) = I$ and
$$ J(v,x) = \left[xI+(1-x) \Lambda(x)\right]\Lambda^{T}(x)\left(I-A\right).$$
Each element of this diagonal matrix is equal to
$$ \left( x + \frac{1-x}{1-x a_{ii}} \right) \frac{1-a_{ii}}{1-x a_{ii}},$$ which is lower than one except at $x = 1$,  in which case it is equal to one.

How can I extend this to show that all diagonal elements of $J(v,x)$ are less than one for all $v,x$?